# Deleting multiple items from a Redis hash, based on a certain value

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis

What is the most efficient way to delete a bunch of items from a hash, based on whether an item's value contains a specific substring or not? As far as I know, there is not really a way to do this in one simple block. I have to literally grab all the values of that hash in a Java list, then iterate over this list till i find what I need, then delete its key from the hash, and repeat the same procedure ove and over again.

Another approach I tried was to put an id references to the the hash items in a separate list, so that later on, with a single call, i could grab a list of id for items which should be deleted. That was a bit better, but still, the redis implementation I use (Jedis) does not support the deletion of multiple hash keys, so again I am left with my hands tied.

Redis does not support referential integrity, right? This means, OK, the keys stored in the Redis list are references to the items in the hash, so if I delete the list, the corresponding items from the hash would eb deleted. There is nothing like that in Redis, right?

I will have to go through this loop and delete every single item separately. I wish at least there was something like a block, where I could collect all 1000 commands, and send them in one entire call, rather than 1000 separate ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
I wish at least there was something like a block,
where I could collect all 1000 commands, and send them in one entire call,
rather than 1000 separate ones.
```

That's what transactions are for: http://redis.io/topics/transactions

Using pipeline would let possible commands from other connected clients to be issued between the pipelined commands, since it only guarantees that your client issues commands without waiting for replies, with no guarantee of atomicity.

Commands in a transaction (i.e. between [MULTI](http://redis.io/commands/multi)/[EXEC](http://redis.io/commands/exec)) are issued atomically, which I presume is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the ids in a Redis List will not affect the Redis Hash Fields. To speed things up consider [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining). Jedis supports that...

Comment: Thanks. I think that's the way to go, too.